# Defining package name regarding buildType in cordova android project

Tags: cordova, android-gradle-plugin, phonegap-plugins, urbanairship.com

How can I define the right package name regarding my buildType ?
I have this command line to build :
`cordova run android --device --buildType=beta`

I have this hook (after prepare) which set the buildType from the command line :

```
fs.appendFileSync( buildExtras, "ext.postBuildExtras = {\nandroid.buildTypes." +
      ( isRelease ? "release" : "debug" ) + ".applicationIdSuffix='." + buildType + "'\n}" );
```

but in AndroidManifest.xml packageName in platforms/android/ is not the right.

Only if I change manually in the config.xml file
`widget id="com.exemple.beta"` then the AndroidManifest.xml package name is correct

Answer (score 0):

Create a `build-extras.gradle` file under `platforms/android/` with the following content:

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
    release {
      applicationIdSuffix ".release"
    }
  }
}
```

I also started to read [cordova 5 documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/platforms/android/tools.html) at first, but since I am using cordova 6 I guess it doesn't work like in their documentation anymore (and I couldn't find the same page in the latest documentation).

Edit 1:
Doing this will not launch the app automatically when doing `cordova run android` anymore, so you will have to launch it manually using `adb shell am start -n com.application.debug/com.application.MainActivity`

Comment: Problem here is that when running `cordova run`, it tries to start application with packageId defined in AnrdoidManfest.xml so without suffix appended by gradle

Comment: @piotr_cz yes you are right, I edited my answer, thanks

Comment: the last cordova documentation says at the file have to be inside platforms/android/app https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html