# Ionic2/Cordova build publish app with different features. Example: Free and Paid

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, android-flavors

I'm developing an application, where it will have a paid (full) version and a free (lite) version.

In another application developed for Android it is possible to manage this easily with flavors (`productFlavors`), where I can configure the replacement of any part of the application. For example: I can configure an applicationId and flag `boolean PAID_VERSION`, for each application as follows:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId 'com.mycompany.myapp.free'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "false"
    }
    paid {
        applicationId 'com.mycompany.myapp.paid'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "true"
    }
}
```

And in the code I can check the `PAID_VERSION` flag of the following way:

```java
boolean b = BuildConfig.PAID_VERSION;
```

And if I want to change the icon and application name by version I should specify in the packages (`applicationId`) of each flavor the specific icon replacing the default, for example:

**String resource application name:**

Free path: `/free/res/values/strings.xml`

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App - Free</string>
</resources>
```

Paid path: `/paid/res/values/strings.xml`

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App - Paid</string>
</resources>
```

**Icon Resource:**

Free path: `/free/res/drawable/icon.png` (Imagem Free)

Paid path: `/paid/res/drawable/icon.png` (Imagem Paid)

---

**Question**

How would it be possible to have a similar configuration to that for a Ionic2/Cordova project, which is possible with the same code base generate 2 applications with a few different features, to be distributed in stores simultaneously and independently?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you may have stumbled into this already, but [this guy created this Gulp tasks](http://blog.davidgray.photography/handling-free-and-paid-versions-of-a-cordova-app/) to modify the `config.xml` file on build-time for this purpose.

Also [in this forum topic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/handling-free-and-paid-versions-of-an-app/63100) he explains how to obtain the current version for conditional in-app code.

Another related topics are: [Configure build flavors for cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713401/configure-build-flavors-for-cordova) which recommends using Cordova Hooks to modify the `config.xml` file based on enviroment variables, as discussed in here: [Using environment variables / parameterizing config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816035/using-environment-variables-parameterizing-config-xml)