# How to use two different packages for two different built variant in cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying two use to different packages dynamically for my two different types of builds. [Went through this link](http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/). But I am unable to understand where should I add the codes to differentiate between stage and prod in android studio. 
I do not know where and how the config file should be added/edited.

Please help me on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What Cordova version do you use?

Comment: I am using 7.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this if you are using `Gradle` to build your Cordova App.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41886578/5457878

Where `applicationIdSuffix` appends the defined value to the actual package name.